# Java equivalent of python's raise Exception("Something went wrong")

Tags: java

What is the best way to raise a generic exception in Java without thinking much about which of the more specific exceptions should be used? I am thinking of (but don't know if this is best):

```
throw new RuntimeException("Something went wrong");
```

Comment: you are correct

Comment: though new word should be added

Comment: What about using the Exception class?

Comment: google checked exceptions vs unchecked

Comment: *"Best"* almost always *depends* on the situation. A simple `RuntimeException` is certainly the easiest way. Using `Exception` is basically the worst option.

Comment: If you plan on catching that exception and perform specific actions, you should ideally make an exception subclass

Comment: if you are not providing useful information in your exception that wouldn't help the caller.

Comment: Why is RuntimeException preferable to Exception?

Comment: There is a useful description of different types of "generic failure" in the [Guava documentation](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ConditionalFailuresExplained). It's worth thinking a little bit about what sort of failure you are trying to report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on what kind of exception it is. In Java –and I should add that this is one of the things that is criticised most about Java– there are checked and unchecked exceptions:

- Checked exceptions (anything deriving from `java.lang.Excetption`, but not from `java.lang.RuntimeException`) are thrown if something went wrong with a resource or operation, and this could be more or less expected: a file was not found, a network link went down, etc
- Unchecked exceptions (anything deriving from from `java.lang.RuntimeException`) are mostly thrown by the language or a library, and are thrown because you have a bug in your code

Again, it's very easy to get into a heated argument about  this, and it is beyond the scope of your question. The guy behind C# looked at Java and thought: "I won't be having with that" and got rid of checked exceptions altogether.

But this is Java, so we have two kinds of exceptions. Therefore, if you want to do things the way that Java was designed, you should throw a checked or an unchecked exception, based on the kind of thing that went wrong.

Having said all that, there is a clear trend that programmers use unchecked exceptions more and more, primarily because checked exceptions are a pain in the you-know-what, and because meaningful exception handling is not as clear-cut in real life as it is when designing a language.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right, this could world:

```
throw new RuntimeException("error message");
```

You can also do a slightly more specific exception

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("error message");
throw new IllegalStateException("error message");
throw new UnsupportedOperationException("error message");
```

Answer (score 0):

throw new RuntimeException("message"); // you don't have to declare this in the method signature.

```
void doSomething1() {
   throw new RuntimeException("");
}
```

throw new Exception("message"); //you have to declare this in method signature; like:

```
void doSomething2() throws Exception{
   throw new Exception("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There're different kinds of exceptions in Java, such as `Throwable`, `Error`, `Exception` and `RuntimeException`. According to SonarQube ([squid : S1181](https://sbforge.org/sonar/rules/show/squid:S1181?layout=false)), `Throwable` is the superclass of all errors and exceptions in Java. `Error` is the superclass of all errors which are not meant to be caught by applications. So you should use either a checked exception `Exception` or an unchecked exception (aka runtime exception) `RuntimeException`.

> What is the best way to raise a generic exception in Java without thinking much about which of the more specific exceptions should be used?

As you said, you can throw a runtime exception. I personally prefer a more meaningful exception type, but it's up to you. There's a discussion about [the most commonly used exceptions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502860/what-are-the-most-commonly-used-runtime-exceptions-in-java), such as:

- `IllegalStateException`
- `IllegalArgumentException`

See also: [Java Language Specification, §11. Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html)